# Qu'est-ce que c'est, « la fête de la Violette » ?

Tags: politique

As mentioned [here](http://www.leparisien.fr/politique/ump-une-fete-de-la-violette-pour-sarkozy-un-barbecue-pour-juppe-04-07-2015-4918511.php#xtref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F), Sarkozy gave a speech in a "fête de la Violette".

Can anyone give more details partaining this event? 
(Searching for it on google only returns more articles like the one above...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est une *[manifestation politique](http://www.lanouvellerepublique.fr/Loir-et-Cher/Services/Toutes-les-DMAs/n/Contenus/DMAs/2015/07/04/La-Fete-de-la-violette-s-ouvre-a-La-Ferte-Imbault-Loir-et-Cher-2392551)* :

Les sarkozystes de la Droite forte, premier courant de l’UMP (maintenant Les Républicains), ont organisé un samedi de juillet 2013 en Sologne leur *première* « fête de la Violette », destinée à devenir « la grande fête annuelle de la droite ».

Il ne s'agit pas de fêter la fleur *violette* comme *[la Fête de la Violette de Toulouse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violette_de_Toulouse)*, née en 1993, mais de donner un nom symbolique à un rassemblement festif.

Answer (score 0):

La fête de la violette a été créée il y a deux ans par le courant UMP/Les Républicains "La Droite Forte" pour répondre à la fête de la rose organisée par le Parti Socialiste.

Source: http://www.ladroiteforte.fr/#une-tabs-hor3|demo-tabs-vert2